# Search partial words or wildcard with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search as below I got result successfully. This is also valid for sentences (or complete words). However, partial words does not find anything.

For example lets have a look at this sentence:

```
embedded image can place here.
```

When I search `embedded` it finds this content. But `embed` does not find anything.

Let me show you:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "Embedded"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "inbox",
        "_type" : "mailbox",
        "_id" : "8c76f6a5-115a-4102-94e6-a3abef914d13",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "user_id" : 10,
          "content" : "Embedded image"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, lets search word `embed` only:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "Embed"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**: Empty...

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 6,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to find related contents when search like this? Please note that it should also find when i search `embed image`

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "content": "embed image"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `query_string`

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "embed image",
            "fields": [
              "content"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```